# I am only able to undo once in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, undo

I can only undo once in Excel and I have taken the steps to change the number in the Edit Registry and that did not fix the problem.

Comment: Did you reboot after changing the registry?  Which registry key did you change?  What did you change it to?

Answer (score 4):

I had a the same problem and the microsoft article instructions to add UndoHistory key to the registry did not help.  I looked for macros that could be running - though that might be the problem, but there were none.  Also checked the XLSTART folder - but no problems there.  I finally found that it was an add-in that was causing the issue.  It was a COM add-in from ASPEN Tech, but I would guess other add-ins may also cause the issue.  If you are still having the issue I recommend disabling add-ins then checking to see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you were following [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211922) to change the value. In most cases a registry key change requires the application to be restarted (no need to reboot the machine for application level changes), or better yet - to do the change, while the application is not running. Otherwise there's a chance that the application can overwrite your change.

So, make sure you have closed excel completely before you change the value in the registry. Open the task manager. Click on the process tab. Check if there is still excel.exe process running. If so, kill it.

Then make your change and start excel.